# eclipse says there is an error in the line, even when I fixed it

Tags: eclipse

Good afternoon,

I am using eclipse for developing. When I spell a variable wrong or so, I, of course, get an error notification. But when I fix it, the little red circle with the white cross is still there. I can only make them go away by cutting out the line and pasting it back in as it was before - the error goes away and I can launch my program. How can I fix this?

Comment: does project->clean help?

Comment: when i click on project, i don't have a "clean" option (i also don't habe an error atm). where can i find it? also, thanks for your answer. I am a beginner regarding java and eclipse.

Comment: click on project menu item (top menu)

Comment: thats weird. now i have the option. i guess i clicked some wrong button. thank you, i'll try it if i have another error.